# Tomcat reference css and js in basic Springboot web app

Tags: java, html, css, tomcat9

Complete beginner here, I've made a web-app in Springboot for my Uni's Tomcat server using Intellij community. I don't have much access to everything on the server but I can deploy .war files. So the web-app deploys ok, but non of the css and js files reference properly. I've tried using absolute referencing eg. from href="/css/navbar" to href="css/navbar", I've tried adding ./ and also resources/static but no success. I was using [this example](https://www.springcloud.io/post/2022-09/springboot-tomcat/#gsc.tab=0) as a reference but from what I've researched most say I need to add update the web.xml with something like:

```
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/js/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
```

But my app doesn't have a web.xml. Below is my file structure and (I assume you need) the pom.xml, home.html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>net.javaguides</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-thymeleaf-crud-web-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-thymeleaf-crud-web-app</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot and thymeleaf</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.24</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link href="css/fontawesome/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navbar.css" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ines.css" >
    <title>InES Employee</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div th:replace="/fragments/chartNavbar :: navbar"></div>
<div class="container">
    <h2>InES Server Page</h2>
    <div class="subContainer">
        <div id="squareButtons" class="wrap">
            <a class="btn" href="#" th:href="@{/ines/employees}">Employees</a>
            <a class="btn" href="#" th:href="@{/ines/projects}">Projects</a>
            <a class="btn" href="#" th:href="@{/ines/chart}">Charts</a>
            <a class="btn" href="#" th:href="@{/ines/labChemicals}">Lab Chemicals</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script th:src="@{./resources/static/js/navbar.js}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Structure

[image]
[image]

And error in chrome console
[image]

Thanks in advance, hopefully its something simple.

Comment: Try using `@{/js/navbar.js}` directly.

Comment: Yeah that did it, thanks man. I also had to change the href to th:href. Rookie mistake.